# ng content not displaying on screen nor in terminal

Tags: angular

Hello I am trying to get the " to display my text on the screen and the console terminal. I get nothing, you hear me nothing at all. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I have tried everything I've researched on the internet. Nothing works

**app.component.html**

```
<bootstrap-panel>
    <div heading>Header</div>
    <div body></div>
</bootstrap-panel>
```

**panel.component.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"> 
        <ng-content select="[heading]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body"> 
        <div class="body">
         <h2>Body</h2>
         <p>Some Content here.....</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Nothing displays in the terminal. I don't see my "ng-content" from the app.component.html I only see the  from then panel.component.html.**

**The only reason the  is displaying is because I actually have it inputed in to the panel.component.html.**

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.19",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

I was expecting it to display on the screen without any problems. Could someone see what is going on here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What, if any, errors are displayed in the browser console?

Comment: none at all is the weird part. Take a look ![Terminal Picture & Screen Display](https://www.online-convert.com/downloadFile/a85a984e-af1b-48e1-911a-587e54d99339/085bd87b-a986-4b1e-bc32-5bf2a4b6a2f6)

Comment: can you move `<ng-content select="[heading]"></ng-content>` out of all blocks and check what do you see, The code you provided related to ng-content has no issue and should be working so the problem could be on something else

Comment: check this, as I mentioned it should be working
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-56971674ng-content-not-displaying-on-screen-nor-in-term

Comment: @RezaRahmati Thank you so much it working now. I guess Angular ng-content does not like the <br>. But I wonder why? Thanks problem solved.